# axis find by keyword in python Seaborn facetgrid

Tags: seaborn, facet-grid

I draw Seaborn Facetgrid and want to search a specific ax by keyword.
For example,
how can I search ax for time=dinner, Smoker=No?

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col='smoker', row='time', size=5, aspect=1.5)
g.map_dataframe(sns.boxplot, y='tip', x='sex')
```

Using below code can only search ax by index.

```
for ax in g.axes[0]:
```

Comment: `for ax in g.axes.flat: print(ax.get_title())`

Comment: Also, from seaborn 0.11.2, directly using `FacetGrid` is not recommended, use `sns.catplot` instead. `g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=tips, x='sex', y='tip', col='smoker', row='time')`.

Comment: You can use `FacetGrid.axes_dict` for this (although if you're using `size=`, you're on a very old seaborn and won't have it).